# Find a matrix that is associated with the eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find a $2×2$ matrix $A$ for which 
$E_{-1}=span \begin{bmatrix}-2 \\-5 \end{bmatrix}, E_1=span\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\-3 \end{bmatrix} $
where $E_{\lambda}  $denotes the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda.$

---

I tried 
$-2a -5c=2\\
-2b-5d=5\\
-a-3c=-1\\
-b-3d=-3$

but I ended up getting lost and confused onto what to do next.

Comment: There are 4 equations in 4 unknowns. Just solve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cleverer way (different from the approach stated in the question) is to note that eigenvectors and eigenvalues are intricately linked with the diagonalisation of a matrix. Thus we immediately get in this case
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}-2&-1\\-5&-3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-2&-1\\-5&-3\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-11&4\\-30&11\end{bmatrix}$$